# JavaScript array comparisions and display values from another

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a case where I need to compare between two arrays and display values from another.;
For example, I have two arrays:

```
let a = ['a','b','c'];
let b = ['textA' 'textB', ' '];
```

So, I am basically trying to loop over the array b and display value like this:

```
   textA
   textB
   C
```

So, when there are any empty values found in array b, display the same indexed values from array a.

Can anybody help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a space is not an empty string. what have you tried?

Comment: a for loop over the indices. if empty string get the value for that index from a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can :

- trim the value to see if there is empty or only space
  `elem.trim().length`
- if string is empty check if data in other array exist if `(!elem.trim().length && a[index])`

```js
let a = ['a','b','c'];
let b = ['textA', 'textB', ' '];

b.forEach((elem, index) => {
  if (!elem.trim().length && a[index]) {
    console.log(a[index]);
  } else {
    console.log(elem);
  }
});
```

One other solution consist to create a result array with array.map and display all key of this new array

```js
let a = ['a','b','c'];
let b = ['textA', 'textB', ' '];


let result = b.map((elem, index) => (!elem.trim().length && a[index]) ? a[index] : elem);

console.log(result);
```